# SQL запрос на дату и отсутствие совпадений

Tags: sql, access

Есть две таблицы `Cars` и `Sales` с полями:

- `Cars` — `Auto_ID`, `Type`
- `Sales` — `Sale_ID`, `Car`, `Date_of_sale`

`Cars.Auto_ID` связан с `Sales.Car` (числовые).

Как найти все модели машин (`Type`), которые не продавались в 2017 году? Суть в том, что если модель машины продавалась 2 (или более) раза в 2017 и в 2018, то она уже не должна выводиться.

Выводит модели не продаваемые в 2017, даже если они продавались в другие года:

```
SELECT Type
FROM Cars INNER JOIN Sales ON Cars.Auto_ID = Sales.Car
WHERE NOT(Year(Sales.Date_of_sale))=2017
```

Comment: которые **не** продавались в 2017 году. Здесь нет опечатки?

Comment: Нет опечатки. Т.е. если Nissan не продавался в 2017, но продавался в 2018, то он будет выведен(т.к. две строки в Sales с Nissan), а он не должен выводиться, ведь нужны именно те марки/модели, которые не продавались в 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT
  Type
FROM
  Cars
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      Sales
    WHERE
      Cars.Auto_ID = Sales.Car AND
      Year(Sales.Date_of_sale) = 2017
  )
```

Тест: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cacbd/1

Comment: То, что нужно. Благодарю.